# WP - WooCo. - Compare - Button

Tags: woocommerce, compare

I am using Wordpress for my online shop. 
I have a problem. On the page with the product, I added a button for comparing the products. All is well but I want that after pressing the button, it becomes invisible.

```
<?php
$session_data = $be_product_compare->session->get_session_cookie();
if( is_array( $session_data ) && in_array( get_the_ID(), $session_data ) ) 
{ echo BE_Compare_Products::display_button( ''.get_the_ID() . '' );

}
else
{
echo ' disabled=disabled ';
}
?>
```

And I get

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_session_cookie() on null
>   in

Can someone help me finish with this Button?

Comment: As explained on this error `$be_product_compare->session` is null so you ca't use `get_session_cookie()` method on it.

Comment: `function add_button() {
global $be_product_compare; `


I have try... same problem.